# Java: Swing Timer waiting

Tags: java, swing, timer, swingworker

I have such a code:

```
final SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() { 
      @Override
      protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {...};
}
Timer timer=new Timer(10000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            worker.execute(); 
        }
    });
    timer.start();
```

Sometimes **worker** procedure takes more than 10 seconds, but sometimes 3-4sec, so how to set the **timer** to wait for the full execution of **worker** ? Any suggestions?

Comment: Swing Timer is inside SwingWoker class???, if yes move that out of SwingWorker class, otherwise post short and runnable  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/http://example.com)

Comment: sorry, i haven't rewritten it correctly. Of course Timer is outta SwingWorker class

Comment: then post an SSCCE demonstrated your issue, otherwise your question is too hard answerable ...

Comment: worker updates RSS feeds, so it depends on current website  availability, connection speed etc
So it's not necessary to post full code here. Important thing is that the execution usually takes less than this 10sec, but I wanna handle situation when it may take longer

Comment: accepted, then all answers here could be only the shots to the dark, why bothering, right ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the javadoc of the `SwingWorker` class:

> Before the doInBackground method is invoked on a worker thread, SwingWorker notifies any PropertyChangeListeners about the state property change to StateValue.STARTED. After the doInBackground method is finished the done method is executed. Then SwingWorker notifies any PropertyChangeListeners about the state property change to StateValue.DONE.

So events are fired when the `SwingWorker` is done. Attach a listener and re-activate your `Timer` on the correct event.